# Does $\log\sqrt x$ grow as fast as $4\log x$ or slower?

Tags: logarithms, computational-complexity

Does $\log\sqrt x$ grow as fast as $4\log x$ or slower? Based on their function diagram, I would guess that $\log\sqrt x$ is slower. However
$$\lim_{ x\to \infty} \frac {\log (\sqrt x)}{\log x} = 1/8$$

So we can conclude that $\log\sqrt x$ grows as fast as $4\log x$. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It’s a direct consequence of the logarithm rule about powers

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you forget $4$ in the denominator of the limit?

Comment: In order to properly answer your question, you need to define 'fast' and 'slower'. Often we say that $g$ is 'faster than' $f$ if $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$. Here, this is not the case. However, we *can* say that $4\log x$ is $8\times$ as big as $\log{\sqrt{x}}$, as outlined in heropup's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\log \sqrt{x} = \log x^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2} \log x.$$  So the ratio $$\frac{4 \log x}{\log \sqrt{x}} = \frac{4}{1/2} = 8.$$  So they are both $O(\log x)$ but obviously one is a constant multiple of the other.